# What is a construct like "data found" (vs "found data") called?

Tags: adjectives, postpositive-adjectives

I learned some time ago that in some cases the "characteristic" of an object, like "found" with respect to "data" is put after the object, i.e. if we found some data we should refer to them as "data found" not "found data". Example sentence:

> The `findData()` function returns the data it finds. To use the *data found*, one must call `useData()`.

I'd like to read more about this construct, but I'm having a hard time trying to formulate a Google query.

Thus my question, what is this construct called?

Comment: Google the word *postpositive*.

Comment: @LucianSava This seems to answer the question, could you turn your comment to a proper answer?

Comment: You need to make clearer, Ruslan, what you mean by "refer to". Providing an example sentence (with any required context) is a good way to ask.

Comment: @TRomano edited to provide an example.

Comment: *found* there could be understood as a kind of *reduced clause* (i.e. "[which has been] found"). *found* there the past-participle of 'find'.

Comment: Although *postpositive* is basically correct (this non-finite clause is an internal post-head modifier in noun phrase structure, and *postpositive* literally means "positioned after"), it might be somewhat confusing in this case.  Why?  Because *postpositive* is usually used to describe (the post-head modifier function of) adjective phrases.

Comment: @LucianSava I'm voting to close as a duplicate. The answers to that question include plenty of terms that can be used to google, and also explain the situation.